# Binary Run Length Encoding , reset counter

Tags: java, arrays, loops, binary, counter

I have an array :  { 0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1 }

I want to count how many 0 there is before 1
and how many 1 before 0 ,

sorry if it's not clear basically 
It should print : 2 , 1 , 2 , 2

(2 zero , 1 one , 2 zero , 2 one )

I need to reset the counter, but I have no idea how to do it

Thank you

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

                int tab[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 }; //
                int count0 = 0;
                int count1 = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
                    if (tab[i] == 0) {
                        count0 = count0 + 1;

                    } else {
                        count1 = count1 + 1;
                    }

                }
                System.out.println(count0 + "\t" + count1);
        // prints 4 3
        // want it to print 2 1 2 2

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset when the value changes from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0.
And also at the very end.

```
for (int num : tab) {
    if (num == 0) {
        count0++;
        if (count1 > 0) {
            System.out.println(count1);
            count1 = 0;
        }
    } else {
        count1++;
        if (count0 > 0) {
            System.out.println(count0);
            count0 = 0;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(Math.max(count0, count1));
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Blebhebhe it's [for-each loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). The syntax exists since Java 5. It's a more idiomatic way to iterate over items in a collection, when you don't need the index, just the items themselves.